# java script countdown timer getting reset on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown

i was trying to implement a countdown for my site but its getting reset on every page refresh, i dont know how to fix that can u guys help me with this?([i used this](https://codepen.io/sander/pen/yhcof))...

```js
var timer;
var compareDate = new Date();
compareDate.setDate(compareDate.getDate() + 16); //incresed by to date + (16 days)

timer = setInterval(function() {
  timeBetweenDates(compareDate);
}, 1000);

function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
  var dateEntered = toDate;
  var now = new Date();
  var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (difference <= 0) {

    // Timer done
    clearInterval(timer);

  } else {

    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    $("#days").text(days);
    $("#hours").text(hours);
    $("#minutes").text(minutes);
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
#timer {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #999;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
#timer span {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0 3px 0 15px;
}
#timer span:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="timer">
  <span id="days"></span>days
  <span id="hours"></span>hours
  <span id="minutes"></span>minutes
  <span id="seconds"></span>seconds
</div>
```

Comment: Well every time your refresh your page the above code will get executed, it's then setting the date to 16 days from then.  If you want it so it's 16 days from when you first enter the page, you will want to do some sort of client side persistence.  The easiest option here is localStorage.

Comment: thanks Keith for your response, if you don't mind can u show me how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Countdown timer resets on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814462/countdown-timer-resets-on-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use localStorage, the following might do.
It will basically store the compareDate on first run..

ps. Due to security attributes in Snippet this won't work here, but should work on your site.

```
var timer;

var savedDate = localStorage.getItem('savedDate');
var compareDate = new Date();
if (savedDate)  {
  compareDate = new Date(savedDate);
} else { 
  compareDate.setDate(compareDate.getDate() + 16); //incresed by to date + (16 days)
  localStorage.setItem('savedDate', compareDate);
}

//...rest of code
```

Comment: No problem.. Just a small note, in future posting's a good idea is to use Stack Overflow's Snippet feature.  It's pretty much the same as say codepen, but with the added bonus of SO users been able to run right inside SO, and easily copy for modifications etc.  I edited your posting for you, you will now see you can click the "Run Code Snippet" to see it in action.  One downside with Snippet, and most likely codepen is the security attributes of the iFrame stop you doing certain things, that's why I didn't use the Copy Snippet as it would't work.. :(

Comment: dear keith i was trying to change the to date , but its not working! its still remain the same?

Comment: Copy / pasting the above code into my console on Chrome, constantly gives me the same DateTime even after refreshing my page.  So I'm not sure why your having issues.  If your say running Chrome under developer tools, under application there is a section called "local Storage"  do you have any entries?  Also I'm assuming your running your HTML pages from a webserver?.

Comment: yes Keith, im running from the webserver. and have a problem, if i run the page the condown is working perfectly without refresh, whereas if i try my page on a different lap or pc , it is starting from the beginning..... , i want to show a deadline for the users.., now the value is different for users to users......

Comment: In this case you will need to persist data server side.  And you will require some way of knowing what user we are talking about.  You will need some login/logout logic.  Localstorage is per browser instance..

Answer (score 0):

Since your countdown calculates the end time when your page starts, it is normal/expected that the countdown will restart every time you refresh the page. In your case, what you are doing is adding 16 days to the current date.

If you want the coutdown not to change, you should add a fixed date, like so:

```
var compareDate = new Date(yyyy,MM,dd,hh,mm,ss);
```

Change the `yyyy`, `MM`, etc. values with years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds like in the following example:

```
var compareDate = new Date(2017,09,10,12,00,00);
```

*N.B.* : this solution doesn't depend of the client. It will display exactly the same countdown for every user connected to the page.

Comment: thanks for your response Louis, but if i do that, if i chk tmrw, it will be start from one day back ryt?

Comment: Yes exactly. If I start it now, and if I go back tomorrow, I will see 15 days remaining